# Oracle JOIN output optimization

Tags: sql, oracle

Using below query I fetch some details scattered across three different tables of a particular oracle database schema...

```
SELECT USERNAME, FULLNAME, DEPARTMENT, TASKNAME 
FROM USERDB t1 
JOIN USERDB_TASKS t3 ON t1.USERID = t3.USERID 
JOIN TASKS t2 ON t3.TASKSID = t2.TASKSID;
```

**Current output:**

```
USERNAME FULLNAME     DEPARTMENT TASKNAME
duryo    dur yogeli   IT         Domain admin
rected   rec tedenson SALES      Process manager
```

Here table USERDB contains four columns USERID, USERNAME, FULLNAME, DEPARTMENT. Table USERDB_TASKS contains two columns USERID, TASKSID. Table TASKS contains two columns TASKSID, TASKNAME.

For a particular user, USERID will be same in all tables. Similarly TASKSID for a particular task will be same in all tables.

But actually there are few USERID in table USERDB which are not there in table USERDB_TASKS i.e. few users do not have any tasks assigned so obviuosly their ids are not there in USERDB_TASKS table.

Using above query I am getting details of only those users whose USERID are present in both USERDB as well as USERDB_TASKS tables. My question is how can I modify my query in such a way that for all those few USERID which are only present in USERDB table and not in USERDB_TASKS table, the value for TASKNAME column should come as NONE, for example like below...

```
USERNAME FULLNAME     DEPARTMENT TASKNAME
duryo    dur yogeli   IT         Domain admin
rected   rec tedenson SALES      Process manager
Ueswit   Ues witer    Market     NONE
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`.  I also strongly recommend that you qualify all column names, so the query would look like:

```
SELECT u.USERNAME, u.FULLNAME, u.DEPARTMENT, t.TASKNAME 
FROM USERDB u LEFT JOIN
     USERDB_TASKS ut
     ON ut.USERID = u.USERID LEFT JOIN
     TASKS t
     ON t.TASKSID = ut.TASKSID;
```

This returns `t.TASKNAME` as a `NULL` value -- which makes a lot of sense to me.  However, if you want `'NONE'`, then use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT u.USERNAME, u.FULLNAME, u.DEPARTMENT,
       COALESCE(t.TASKNAME, 'NONE') as TASKNAME
. . .
```

Comment: @Gordon...It would be so helpful if you could have a look on this issue [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369196/listagg-weird-concatenation] as well...Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use `Left outer join` and `NVL`

```
SELECT USERNAME, FULLNAME, DEPARTMENT, NVL(TASKNAME, 'NONE') 
  FROM USERDB t1 
  JOIN INNER JOIN USERDB_TASKS t3 ON t1.USERID=t3.USERID 
  LEFT OUTER TASKS t2 ON t3.TASKSID=t2.TASKSID;
```